# cannot find package "bufio" in any of

Tags: go, installation

I have get go1.11.5 installed by downloading precompiled binary package directly on my ubuntu18.04. Now i want to install go1.12 by building from source, so i follow with [Installing Go from source](https://golang.google.cn/doc/install/source).

I set **GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=~/goroot_bootstrap**

```
$ mkdir -p ~/goroot_bootstrap/bin
$ cp /usr/local/go/bin/go ~/goroot_bootstrap/bin/
$ echo "export GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=~/goroot_bootstrap" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, get source

```
$ git clone -b release-branch.go1.12 https://github.com/golang/go.git ~/github.com/golang/go
```

Build

```
$ cd ~/github.com/golang/go/src
$ ./all.bash
```

It failed, and tips:

```
Building Go cmd/dist using /home/pi/goroot_bootstrap.
cmd/dist/imports.go:12.2: cannot find package "bufio" in any of:
        /home/pi/goroot_bootstrap/src/bufio (from $GOROOT)
        /home/pi/go/src/bufio (from $GOPATH)
...
```

But if i set *GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/go*, it will success.
Then, i read source code at src/make.bash.

```
166  rm -f cmd/dist/dist
167  GOROOT="$GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP" GOOS="" GOARCH="" GO111MODULE=off "$GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP/bin/go" build -o cmd/dist/dist ./cmd/dist
```

The bootstrap toolchains build cmd/dist with GOROOT="$GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP" at line 167.
If i have *GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/go* set and success, which means building still depending old package such as bufio.

So, why it failed when setting **GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=~/goroot_bootstrap**?
Do building depends old package if setting *GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/go*?
Which one is the right method to install from source?

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: `The scripts that do the initial build of the tools look for an existing Go tool chain in $GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP` -- you need the entire toolchain, not just the `go` binary

Comment: @JimB May be need entire goroot